# Need Help to split text to a row using App script

Tags: google-apps-script

I made a daily student attendance app using Kodular and a spreadsheet as a database. I connected the kodular to a spreadsheet using Appscript. The app worked well, but since I'm a newbie in app script I can only send the data to a spreadsheet as shown below
[image: output from the attendance app]

I need help splitting the text using commas as delimiters into a row. Here's my expectation:
[image]

here's the function I use to call the data from the app, I'm still a newbie and I just know basic functions like this

```
function doPost(e) {
return ceksheet(e);
}

function ceksheet(e){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.SH); 

//CREATE
if (e.parameter.func == "Create") {
  var ts = e.parameter.TIMESTAMP;
  var user = e.parameter.USER;
  var tgl = e.parameter.TANGGAL;
  var kls = e.parameter.KELAS;
  var nama = e.parameter.NAMA;
  var ket = e.parameter.KETERANGAN;
  var data = false;
  var lr = sh.getLastRow();
  for(var i=1;i<=lr;i++){
    var data_ts = sh.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    if(data_ts==ts){
      data=true;
    } 
  }
  if (data){
    var result= "ID Sudah ada";
  }else{
    var rowData = sh.appendRow([ts,user,tgl,kls,nama,ket]);  
    var result="Berhasil Input";
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

FYI, here's the image of the app
[image: attendance app]
As you can see in the blue box, I intended to compile the data as one label per component ( timestamp in one label, name in one label, etc) as I planned to split it using appscript, It's just not resolved yet.
Kindly need your help to resolve this problem...